# NodeMCU (ESP8266) board controlled over shared hosting database

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have a NodeMCU (ESP8266) board that I want to control over the internet. I am trying to find a solution where I don't have to set up any configurations on my router like port forwarding. I came up with the following solution:

[image]

I have a website where the user changes the device status (with status I mean for example GPIO5 pin value HIGH or LOW) which is then saved to a database on a shared hosting server. The NodeMCU sends periodically (for example every 5 seconds) a HTTP GET request to the database. According to the value that is received from the database the NodeMCU board changes the pin value to HIGH or LOW. If NodeMCU changes it's status (for example a pin value from HIGH to LOW) the new device status is sent to the database with a HTTP POST request. The device also sends a HTTP POST request periodically (for example every 60 seconds) so the user can monitor the device status on the website.

There are a few problems with this configuration:

1. There is no real-time connection between NodeMCU and the user (there
   is always a delay in the device response)
2. The device sends thousand of queries every day that are a load to
   the shared hosting server. For example if the GET request is sent
   every 5 seconds, that gives 17280 queries per day for one device.

So my question is how practical is this configuration on shared hosting or any kind of hosting, what are the alternatives or improvements to this configuration and how to establish a connection with the NodeMCU so that the device sends a GET request to the database only when the device status is changed in the database by the user.

Comment: a HTTP request can wait until the server has something to send as a response

Comment: @Juraj please check out my question at stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932766/postpone-http-get-response-until-the-user-changes-the-value-in-the-database

Comment: you can check if the client is still connected and if not, send the request again. but I don't know how to handle the php side

Comment: just use websockets; a 2-way always-connected low-overhead protocol supported by webserver platforms and ESPs. You could also use server-sent events, which almost any php box can support, and for which you can semi-easily mod the existing ESP libs to handle.

Comment: @dandavis can I use websockets without the need to configure my router (for example setting port forwarding)

Comment: websockets works without adjusting any router settings.

Comment: @dandavis I tried to use websockets but I had some difficulties on finding an example (how to install a websocket server on a shared hosting server) on the internet. Do you know where I can find an example where the websocket server is on a shared hosting server and the websocket client is an ESP8266

Comment: you probably can't do it on a shared server, you would have to use SSE, a light modification of normal HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MQTT.

You need:

1. The PubSubClient.h library
2. An MQTT server

For MQTT there are some free ones around on the internet (ask Google). Or if you have a Linux server available for use (e.g., a cheap VPS server from one of many many providers online) then you can run your own with `mosquitto`.

MQTT works kind of how you describe, but it's not making constant GET requests - it opens a single connection to the MQTT server and realtime requests are sent down it to the client, and back from the client to the server.

Near realtime communication.